# Stop Div scrolling past another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I have this div container which holds two divs. When scrolled down and the div container is passed by the window it sticks to the top of the screen and follows the screen however when I keep scrolling down, the divs inside the container div overlap the footer.

I cant seem to figure out how to stop the footer from being overlapped, I want it so when the bottom of the div container reaches just short of the footer it stops moving however when scrolling back it up follows the screen still. Currently all it does is follow the screen down when passed and follows it back up to its original position.

Here is the JS for the following part:

```
function sticky_relocate_2() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('.sticky-anchor').offset().top + 210;


    if (window_top > div_top) {
            $('#right_side_inner_container').addClass('sticky_2')


    } else 
            $('#right_side_inner_container').removeClass('sticky_2')

}

google.setOnLoadCallback(function() 
{
     $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate_2);
 sticky_relocate();
});
```

div id=right_side_inner_container thats the id of the container I want to be moving and to stop when it reaches the footer.
div id=footer  id for the footer.

I saw on some other sites that when it reaches a certain point it minuses from the 'top' css so every pixel scrolled past it keeps deducting from it. I cant seem to figure out how to do it though.

any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: an example

http://www.ebuyer.com/197546-gigabyte-ga-890gpa-ud3h-890gx-socket-am3-hdmi-dvi-vga-out-8-channel-audio-ga-890gpa-ud3h

if you look at the right hand div, when you scroll past it sticks to the screen which I can do but when you keep scrolling it down after a short while it stops and doesn't continue. This is what I am struggling to do.

When I use inspect element (chrome) the top css keeps getting deducted.

EDIT 2: added styles:

```
#right_side_inner_container {
    width 300px;
    height: 600px;
    background: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}

#right_side_inner_container.sticky_2 {
    width: 300px;
height: 600px;
background: transparent;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
    margin-top: -8px;
}

#footer {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
margin: 5px 0 0 0;
clear: both;
background: blue;
}
```

I want the right inner container div to stop just before it reaches the footer div. The sticky class is added when the original div is scrolled past which allows it to follow the screen when scrolled past.

Comment: From your comments you said you changed the CSS to fixed (presumably along with other styles), this is the way to go...subtracting pixels and such as you've described above is a inefficient method, would you mind posting your CSS styles?

Comment: Sure i added CSS to the post

Comment: Ok, well you have pretty much the right idea. Heres a fiddle of a quick solution using your concept, dont mind the "fluff" I've added to mimic your situation, just pay attention to the JS and CSS styles for the fixie box: http://jsfiddle.net/z4q3v/

Comment: I think the main problem was then you wee *adding* the offset of your header when you should *subtract* it, and also you should give the fixed box a *top* of that header offset, not zero

Comment: Thanky you very much for the reply I will take a look at this see if I can get it to work for my thing.

Comment: I tried adding it to mine couldnt get it to work :/

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't really help you further without seeing more code, what I suggest is `console.log()` values of the offsets and such inside the scroll function, you will be able to figure out the issue from there. Other than that it's probably a CSS issue that you have.

Comment: yea its nearly working now it stopps at the footer just need to neaten the css now thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding some `padding-bottom` the `<body>` or the scrolling div's container?

Comment: Yea doesnt do anything. when the div is stuck to the screen, i add a css class to it which makes it top: 0 and position fixed so dont know if padding will effect it.

Comment: if you look at http://www.ebuyer.com/197546-gigabyte-ga-890gpa-ud3h-890gx-socket-am3-hdmi-dvi-vga-out-8-channel-audio-ga-890gpa-ud3h the div on the right when you scroll down and then stops at a certain point is what im trying to do. I managed to get it moving when passed just cant get it to stop lol

Comment: sorry do you mean the div at the top how it has a fixed position and doesn't move when you scroll down? i am not following your question 100%

Comment: maybe i explained it badly. If you take a look at http://www.ebuyer.com/197546-gigabyte-ga-890gpa-ud3h-890gx-socket-am3-hdmi-dvi-vga-out-8-channel-audio-ga-890gpa-ud3h the div on the right when you scroll down and then stops at a certain point is what im trying to do. I managed to get it moving when passed just cant get it to stop lol

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using pure CSS to achieve this? You can just simply use the property `overflow:scroll;`?
I have set up an example fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7q9Fw/5/

So that the div's do not overlap you simply just need to use the

```
float:left;
clear:left;
```

attributes and this will set the div's apart.

Comment: thanks for the reply ermm not sure if thats what im trying to do :/ maybe i explained it badly. If you take a look at http://www.ebuyer.com/197546-gigabyte-ga-890gpa-ud3h-890gx-socket-am3-hdmi-dvi-vga-out-8-channel-audio-ga-890gpa-ud3h the div on the right when you scroll down and then stops at a certain point is what im trying to do. I managed to get it moving when passed just cant get it to stop lol